# Include font package only on one page

Tags: fonts, pdftex, packages

I create digest of articles, and I need to use package `\usepackage{nimbussans}` on the title page. But when I included and use it, I have a lot of troubles with all the rest document -- there is not working `textbf{}` and `\bf` for example. How I can disable this package? Or include it only on one page. MacOS, MacTeX, write in VS Code with LaTeX add-on.